# How to add values from a numeric list to a plot title?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add to a ggplot title numeric values from a list. However, only the first value appears correctly (the second one is missing). Why?... How to add all values from the list?

```
# create some data
a = c(4,7,9)
b = c(2,1,3)
mydata <- data.frame(a, b)

# here are my list values I would like to add to the plot title
myList = c(55,95)

# ploting
windows(width=10,height=3)

plot1 = ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point()
plot2 = ggplot(mydata,aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point()

require(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2,nrow=1, ncol=2,
         top = paste("my list:", myList[[1]][1:2]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're intending your title to look like, but maybe something like:

```
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2,nrow=1, ncol=2,
         top = paste("my list:", paste(myList, collapse = ", ")))
```

will get close to what you're after?

**Edit:** Removed unnecessary indexing as per Wil's comment.

Comment: I know OP used `myList[1:2]` but I think you could just use `myList` as well, in the interest of parsimony.